# Independence of Path for Line Integral of Vector Field Perpendicular to Curve

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $C$ be a simple, piecewise-smooth curve between points $A$ and $B$, as shown below:
[image: Depiction of curve and field]

Let $\vec{f}$ be a vector field that is defined on the curve (shown above in blue). The magnitude of $\vec{f}$ is constant everywhere; its direction is perpendicular to the tangent of the curve in the sense indicated. The integral of interest is:
$$\int_{C} \vec{f}dl$$
where $dl$ is differential arclength. Note the result of the integral is a vector.

How do I show the integral is independent of path for all curves $C$, given some end points $A$ and $B$?

(Application: water pressure (simplified to 2 dimensions), for example. $\vec{f}$ can be thought of as a force per unit length on a submerged line, and the integral represents the total force on the line, which is represented by the curve $C$.)

Comment: How does f behaves on the rest of the space?

Comment: @ConradoCosta Thank you for your attention to my question. I've made important corrections and updates to the question. $\vec{f}$ depends on the curve $C$ given ($\vec{f}$ is perpendicular to the curve and does not change sense), so $\vec{f}$ is not unique. However, the magnitude of $\vec{f}$ is constant everywhere. The problem I have in mind is water pressure. If you have suggestions on how better to formulate the problem, please let me know.